# Firebase one to one chat android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am bit confused to create one to one firbase chat application .

My requirement is i need to show the chat list for each users(History of user chats). Once the user clicks one user from list i want to show the one to one chat window with selected user.

but with my format when i send a message to any user all the user got that message and i cant show filtered chat list for particular user it show all the chat history from firebase database

this is my json strucure in firebase

[image]

**java code**

```
    static final String CHAT_REFERENCE = "lifegoal";

ChatFirebaseAdapter firebaseAdapter = new  ChatFirebaseAdapter(mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(CHAT_REFERENCE), userModel.getName(), this);
    rvListMessage.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    rvListMessage.setAdapter(firebaseAdapter);
```

Answer (score 4):

First, you'll have to change the way your database is structured so that you can create a new thread or conversation id for each one to one chat. For example, you can try something like this:

```
- lifegoal
    - senderId-receiverId
        - KNa0...
            - message
            - timestamp
            + usermodel
```

This will allow you create a new threadId unique to both users.

The only caveat is that you'll need to check which child is valid in firebase to know which one to use. For instance, you can try something like this:

`String type_1 = senderId + "_" + receiverId;
String type_2 = receiverId + "_" + senderId;`

And then check in your `onDataChange()` callback like below:

```
   `@Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(type_1)) {
            // do something...
        } else if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(type_2)) {
            // do something...
        } else {
            // do something...
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your format of data saving is wrong. You are sending message in whole thread i.e lifegoal, you need to send it to a single thread where you have stored single user conversion. Take a look at these links

[Firebase : Build a real time chat](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-firebase-chat/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)
[Firebase Chat for Android](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat)
[bonfire-firebase-sample](https://github.com/novoda/bonfire-firebase-sample)

Above links will demonstrate you how firebase chat works and what kind of DataModel you should follow.

[Here](https://github.com/novoda/bonfire-firebase-sample/tree/master/server) they have shown data structure, you can follow that

Comment: but if i stored it in single thread ho can i access it for a specific child