# One to one Chat Facilty

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

An activity is showing list of registered users. After touching any user it goes to chat that user but problem is that it showing same message in every user. MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
ListView usersList;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUser;
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
private DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDatabaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

    usersList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.usersList);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list);
    usersList.setAdapter(adapter);
    usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String s = usersList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Chat_Room.class);
            intent.putExtra("user_name",s);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    mDatabaseUser.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            /*list.add((String) dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));*/

            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            // Check for null
            if (user == null) {
               // Log.e(TAG, "User data is null!");
                return;
            }
            list.add(user.username);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_logout:
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SignActivity.class));
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

Chat_Room.java

```
  public class Chat_Room extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

private EditText metText;
private Button mbtSent;
private DatabaseReference mFirebaseRef;

private List<Chat> mChats;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ChatAdapter mAdapter;
private String mId;

@SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat__room);

    String user_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_name");
    setTitle(user_name);
    metText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etText);
    mbtSent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSent);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvChat);
    mChats = new ArrayList<>();

    mId = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    //mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new SlideInOutLeftItemAnimator(mRecyclerView));
    mAdapter = new ChatAdapter(mChats, mId);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    /**
     * Firebase - Inicialize
     */
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mFirebaseRef = database.getReference("message");
    mbtSent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String message = metText.getText().toString();

            if (!message.isEmpty()) {
                /**
                 * Firebase - Send message
                 */
                mFirebaseRef.push().setValue(new Chat(message, mId));
            }

            metText.setText("");
        }
    });

    mFirebaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                try {

                    Chat model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);

                    mChats.add(model);
                    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mChats.size() - 1);
                    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mChats.size() - 1);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
}
```

Chat.java

```
   public class Chat {
public String message;
public String id;

public Chat() {
}

public Chat(String message, String id) {
    this.message = message;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

ChatAdapter.java

```
    class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private static final int CHAT_END = 1;
private static final int CHAT_START = 2;

private List<Chat> mDataSet;
private String mId;

ChatAdapter(List<Chat> dataSet, String id) {
    mDataSet = dataSet;
    mId = id;
}

@Override
public ChatAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;

    if (viewType == CHAT_END) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_chat_end, parent, false);
    } else {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_chat_start, parent, false);
    }

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (mDataSet.get(position).getId().equals(mId)) {
        return CHAT_END;
    }

    return CHAT_START;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Chat chat = mDataSet.get(position);
    holder.mTextView.setText(chat.getMessage());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSet.size();
}

/**
 * Inner Class for a recycler view
 */
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView mTextView;

    ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
    }
}
}
```

How to improve this so that on touching each user it shows the chat message with that user not same for all users message.

[image: Image of database]

Comment: kindly share your firebase database structure along with this question.

Comment: I have added the image of database

Comment: I think as of now by seeing your database structure, I recommend you to change your database structure. In case you need to see samples how to create and manage your firebase datatabase there are numerous of options available on github and as well as on google . I am attaching few of links [link1](https://github.com/crazyhitty/firebase-chat),  [link2](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0) and [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41263822/5308778), If you need references you can check them.